# Where do you place a simple variable in the Ember App Kit file structure so it can be accessed by a template file?

Tags: ember.js

Using this example: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/facaf/2/)

Where would I put this line of code:

```
App.name = 'White'
```

in the EAK file structure so that it will render on the index page as in the example?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the right way. But generally EAK tries to avoid polluting the global namespace. So a method to have globals accessible every where is to use initializers to register a globals dependency and inject them to all the controllers. This is the same way ember data injects the store to the controller.

Inside `app/initializers` create `global.js` file

```
var globals = Ember.Object.extend({
  name: 'Edgar Allen Poe'
});

export default {
  name: "Globals",

  initialize: function(container, application) {
    container.typeInjection('component', 'store', 'store:main');
    application.register('global:variables', globals, {singleton: true});
    application.inject('controller', 'globals', 'global:variables');
  }
};
```

This will inject the globals to all the controllers.
You can refer it in a template like

```
{{globals.name}}
```

Comment: That's great however I find this nuts! Where do you even began to figure out these kind of things?? Is there some low level docs of ember somewhere besides the source code itself?

Comment: @user391986 Check this out http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/dependency-injection-and-service-lookup/

Comment: Also how do you access the global variables in a Route or Controller?

Comment: @david-douglas you can access as this.get('globals');

Answer (score 0):

Putting this in initializers is great but if your app is not using much global data or just need a flag, can use it directly :

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create(
  ready: ->
    this.register('current:view', window.current_view, {instantiate: false});
    this.inject('controller', 'isCurrentView', 'current:view');
  rootElement: '#ember-app'
)
```

Now you access {{isCurrentView}} in all templates