# Defining custom Ember.Object in Ember-CLI

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Question Revised: 04/30/2015

I would like to define a new `Ember.Object.extend()`  somewhere in my Ember CLI project, so that I can make new object instances from it using a line like  `myObject.create()`

Is it correct to store these in a directory like `app/custom-objects`?  and then i can do something like `import myObject from './custom-objects/my-object'`

Is an initializer required to register the object into ember, before I can import it?

Is my assumption here correct?

Comment: This might be what you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/a/23729225/548568

Comment: @blessenm thanks for that... you know ember-cli removed the "initializers" directory from it's default installation, so i assumed (because I am still new) that perhaps it was a deprecated thing... but apparently it will still work if I add it in.  I will give it a go :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Initializer is not required.

You could define `myObject`:

```
//app/custom-objects/my-object.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Object.extend({
   name: 'DefaultName'
});
```

and then you could import it anywhere:

```
//app/pods/parent/children/controller.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import MyObject from '../../../custom-objects/my-object'

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  //...
  myObj: MyObject.create({name: 'SuperName'}),
});

//app/pods/parent/children/template.hbs
name: {{myObj.name}} {{!--  => SuperName --}}
```