# General Site related settings in an Ember-CLI App?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm just wondering what's the best place to put site related settings in an `ember-cli` app that you can access on any route/controller, so likely in the global namespace.

By site settings I mean the following: site name, site slogan, default avatar directory, default profile cover directory, etc.

I know I can create a mixin but I feel there is a much better way, possibly in the `environment.js` file? I'm very new to `ember-cli` which is why I might have missed some obvious ways of adding global settings like these.

If anyone has suggestions on where to add these types of settings please give clear direction on how to add it and reference it in controllers / routers as well as why you think that's the best place (or the only place).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23718384/where-do-you-place-a-simple-variable-in-the-ember-app-kit-file-structure-so-it-c/23729225#23729225 this is applicable to ember-cli too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a candidate for a service. Try running

```
ember g service settings
```

from the root of your project. You can now add the shared properties to your new service:

```
// app/services/settings.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Object.extend({
    appName: 'my-app'
});
```

An initializer will also be created for you, which controls how you can access your service throughout your application:

```
// app/initializers/settings.js
export default {
  name: 'settings',
  initialize: function(container, app) {
    app.inject('route', 'settings', 'service:settings');
  }
};
```

As you can see, by default your service is available in all routes. Access it like this:

```
// app/routes/application.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    activate: function() {
        this.get('settings.appName'); // my-app
    }
});
```

To make your service available in controllers, simply inject the service in the initializer:

```
app.inject('controller', 'settings', 'service:settings');
```

---

It can be easy to abuse services as a dumping ground for data you want to share throughout your application. Use them sparingly. In particular, something like a default avatar directory might be more appropriate as a model property.

Comment: In what model would the default avatar directory make sense? I always thought these types of settings are very static and need to be accessed almost everywhere.

Comment: Without knowing more about your app it's hard to tell. Is the avatar for a user? In that case, the `user` model.

Comment: but that's a static thing, why should it be persisted across all user models?

Comment: It doesn't have to live in a database, it could be a static property from your backend. For example, in your user serializer.

Comment: It could also be a static property on your user model in the frontend. Just add a `defaultAvatarUrl` property to the model. Whether it belongs in the frontend or backend depends on what you want your API to expose (e.g. for other consumers).

Comment: I get this error when I try to call `this.get('settings.siteName');` in my afterModel method: `Uncaught TypeError: Invalid Fullname, expected: `type:name` got: settings `

Comment: I've got this     `app.inject('controller', 'route', 'settings', 'service:settings');`

Comment: @user1952811 still having trouble? Jump in #ember-cli